Error when installing appium using npm "sudo npm install -g appium"
Error when installing appium using npm "sudo npm install -g appium"
npm -v : 10.5.0
Node -v : v21.7.3'
`'aldo123@DESKTOP-8LUHHTT:~$ sudo npm install -g appium'
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'crc32-stream@6.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js
npm ERR! /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/scripts/autoinstall-extensions.js:45
npm ERR!   process.stderr.columns ?? process.stdout.columns ?? 80
npm ERR!                           ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
npm ERR!     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
npm ERR!     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-04-16T06_24_29_318Z-debug-0.log`


The error message is pretty clear. Your node version is to old. Upgrade.
